# Evolution operator for "blending" a pair of eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Consider a measurement operator ("observable") $\hat O$ which has ("a spectrum of") only two distinct eigenvectors; formally

$$\hat O |\bullet\rangle := r_{\bullet}~|\bullet\rangle, \qquad \hat O |\circ\rangle := r_{\circ}~|\circ\rangle, \qquad \langle \bullet |\circ\rangle = 0, $$

where the eigenvalues $r_{\bullet}$ and $r_{\circ}$ are (suitable) real numbers.

Is there a time-dependent unitary operator $\hat U[~t~]$ such that

$$ \frac{|\bullet\rangle + |\circ\rangle}{\sqrt 2} = \hat U[~t_{\text{blend}}~] ~ |\bullet\rangle $$ 
?

If so, can this operator be expressed in the form  $\hat U[~t~] := \text{Exp}[~\frac{-i~t}{\hbar}~\hat H[~t~]~]$ ?

If so, can the corresponding operator $\hat H[~t~]$ be expressed in terms of the given operator $\hat O$, or its eigenvectors or eigenvalues, and, as necessary, the coordinate value $t_{\text{blend}}$ and the coordinate variable $t$?

---

**Edit**
(along with correcting the above "evolution equation" stated within the bra-ket formalism):

Within the [density matrix formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#The_Von_Neumann_equation_for_time_evolution) it could be asked correspondingly whether there is a time-dependent unitary operator $\hat U[~t~]$ such that

$$ \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \array{ |\bullet\rangle\langle\bullet | & |\bullet\rangle\langle\circ | \cr |\circ\rangle\langle\bullet | & |\circ\rangle\langle\circ | } \right) = \hat U[~t_{\text{blend}}~] ~ \left( \begin{array}{cc} |\bullet\rangle\langle\bullet | & 0 \\ 0 & |\circ\rangle\langle\circ | \end{array} \right) ~ \hat U[~t_{\text{blend}}~]^{\dagger}.$$

Answer (score 2):

OK firstly operators act on kets as vectors, so for some unitary operator $\hat{U}$, the action of $\hat{U}$ sends $|\psi\rangle\rightarrow \hat{U}|\psi\rangle$ not $\hat{U}|\psi\rangle\hat{U}^\dagger$, which is normally not a well defined expression.

For the rest of your question, since we are only dealing with a two dimensional space (or at least only a two dimensional subspace of some larger space) it is clearest to use matrix notation. So
\begin{equation}
\hat{U}(t) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)\quad 
|\bullet\rangle = \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)\quad 
|\circ\rangle = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

In this notation your blending condition becomes \begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}a\\c\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
The requirement that $\hat{U}$ be unitary then fixes $b$ and $d$ up to a sign, so it is easy to work out that\begin{equation}
\hat{U} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1& \pm 1\\1&\mp 1\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

If we put the minus sign in the top right (the case where it is in the bottom right differs only by a change of basis) then $\hat{U}$ has a standard representation in terms of Pauli matrices\begin{equation}
\hat{U} = \exp\left(-\imath\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma^{\,y}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: By Symmetry: "_OK firstly operators act on kets as vectors [...]_ $|\psi\rangle \rightarrow \hat U |\psi\rangle$" -- Aw; thanks for clarifying (+1). So, what I wrote at least doesn't work with "bra-ket" notation ... (I may need a while for deciding whether and how to correct/edit my OP regarding this "formality".) "_[...] clearest to use matrix notation._" -- Great. However: I'm missing some **explicit $t$ dependence** in your expressions for operator $\hat U[~t~]$. (This still seems a substantive part of my question which you answer didn't address.)

Comment: @user12262 Just replace $\pi/4$ in the expression for $\hat{U}$ by anything of the form $\Omega t$, where $\Omega$ has dimensions of frequency and $t$ is time. Then you get your required unitary operator by setting $\Omega t_\mathrm{blend} = \pi/4$.

Comment: @Mark Mitchison: "_Just replace $\pi/4$ in the expression for $\hat U$ by anything of the form_ $\Omega~t$ [with] $\Omega~t_{\text{blend}} = \pi/4$. Can you please prove that: $$\hat U[~t_{\text{blend}}~]=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(\array{1&-1\cr 1&1}\right) =?= \text{Exp}[~i~\frac{\pi}{4}~\hat \sigma_y~] = \text{Exp}[~i~\frac{\pi}{4}~{\left(\array{0&-i \cr i&0}\right)}~]=\text{Exp}[~\frac{\pi}{4}~\left(\array{ 0 & 1 \cr -1 & 0}\right)~]$$ ? (Meanwhile I ponder [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#The_Von_Neumann_equation_for_time_evolution) ...)

Comment: @user12262 firstly I realised I missed a minus sign in my expression for $\hat{U}$. The expression for $\hat{U}$ follows straightforwardly from the power series definition of the matrix exponential and the fact that $\hat{\sigma}_y^2 = \hat{I}$

Comment: @user12262 You have the identity, which you can prove using the arguments in By Symmetry's comment: $$ e^{i \theta\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{\sigma}} = \cos(\theta) + i\hat{\mathbf{x}}\cdot \mathbf{\sigma} \sin(\theta), $$ where $\sigma$ here is a vector of Pauli operators $\sigma^{x,y,z}$, and $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ is a unit vector parallel to $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: By Symmetry: "_[...] straightforwardly [... with]_" $\hat\sigma_y^2=\hat I$ -- Now I realize: $$\text{Exp}[-i~\frac{\pi}{4}~\hat\sigma_y~]=\text{Cos}[~\frac{\pi}{4}~\hat \sigma_y~]-i~\text{Sin}[~\frac{\pi}{4}~\hat\sigma_y~]=\text{Cos}[~ \frac{\pi}{4} ~]~\hat I-i~\text{Sin}[~\frac{\pi}{4}~]~\hat\sigma_y,$$ etc. This makes for the given problem: $$\hat H := \frac{-i~\hbar~\hat \sigma_y}{t_{\text{blend}}}.$$ So, thanks again! Now, having solved this homework, how about trying to tackle [the corresponding general problem (PSE/q/177107)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177107/) ... ?

Comment: @Mark Mitchison: (I saw your recent comment only after I had started to prepare my reply to By Symmetry; thanks anyways ...) So, for the given problem, you're suggesting not (just) $$\hat H := \frac{-i~\hbar~\hat\sigma_y}{t_{\text{blend}}},$$ but more generally: $$\hat H := \frac{-i~\hbar~\mathbf x\cdot\hat{\mathbf \sigma}}{t_{\text{blend}}}.$$ This does indeed seem to allow more "freedom" when trying to derive an expression for $\hat H[~t~]$ for [the corresponding general problem (PSE/q/177107)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177107/) (where there may even be an explicit $t$ dependence).